# regarding validate request property

Tags: asp.net

what are the possible benefits of using ValidateRequest request to set false in asp.net page?

Because I'm going to use it.

Comment: Benefits? It doesn't complain when I use JavaScript to actually get some work done :)

Comment: in all versions of Dot.Net lower than 4.0 it's useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "benefit" is that you have more control over the input validation. If `ValidateRequest = true` and the input has invalid characters then an ugly error page is showed to the user.

Although a little old, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx) you have a MSDN post about "Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET"

Answer (score 0):

Validate Request is essentially a terrible design. It was a good idea and would have worked but there is no good way to catch the exception and report error back to user as one would want. The exception can't be caught except at app level.

Also, you can use regular expression validator to avoid the exception but even if you have server side validation and Javascript is turned off then the exception is thrown.